# Arrays in Processing

Tags: arrays, processing

I'm quite new to programming and have recently started in Processing.
In my code, the collide function sets the touch boolean to be true but by arraying it, it only tests true for the final array and not the ones before it. Where am I going wrong here? I hope my question is clear enough.

edit:

Sorry, let me try again.
I guess my problem is finding out how to array the collide function properly. I cant seem to add a [i] for the collide in the array.
At the moment, the code works but it only tests true for the last array and not for the ones before it.

The array code:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < lineDiv; i++){ 
collide(xPts[i], yPts[i], vecPoints.xPos, vecPoints.yPos, myDeflector.Thk, vecPoints.d);
```

The collide function:

```
void collide(float pt1x, float pt1y, float pt2x, float pt2y, int size1, int size2){
if (pt1x + size1/2 >= pt2x - size2/2 && 
pt1x - size1/2 <= pt2x + size2/2 && 
pt1y + size1/2 >= pt2y - size2/2 && 
pt1y - size1/2 <= pt2y + size2/2) {
touch = true;
}
else{
touch=false;
}
```

Comment: Your hopes are hopeless :) ... please explain more, difficult to understand the problem.

Comment: what do you mean by "arraying the `touch` boolean"?

Comment: I think you mean that the `collide()` function only returns true for the last arguments passed to it, right? (i.e. when `i` equals lineDiv). You should explain what you expect to happen and *why*.

Answer (score 1):

Your "touch" variable is global.  Every time you call the collide() function, it overwrites whatever it was set to before.  Perhaps you just want to test if touch is true after calling collide(), then exit the for loop?

Alternatively, you may want to make collide() return the touch boolean, avoiding the global.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want to do is to run through a loop, run the function on that element of the array and return a value if any of them are true. This is my best guess, you might want to edit your question to clarify what you are looking to do. So assuming this:

1) change you method to a function

```
boolean collide(float pt1x, float pt1y, float pt2x, float pt2y, int size1, int size2){
if (pt1x + size1/2 >= pt2x - size2/2 && 
pt1x - size1/2 <= pt2x + size2/2 && 
pt1y + size1/2 >= pt2y - size2/2 && 
pt1y - size1/2 <= pt2y + size2/2) {
return true;
}
else{
return false;
}
```

2) change your loop and how you are calling it

```
touch = false;  // if you don't set this to false before the loop, it will be the last value taken
for(int i = 0 ; i < lineDiv; i++){ 
     if (collide(xPts[i], yPts[i], vecPoints.xPos, vecPoints.yPos, myDeflector.Thk, vecPoints.d)) touch = true;
```

Before the action would be that touch might cycle between true and false as you iterate through the array and in processing (because you would likely draw out the data) it is unlikely that you would want this behavior because you wouldn't be able to do anything with it unless you packed that data in another structure like an array.

So now, the "touch" is set to false and will change to true if any function calls return a true. If all are false, it will stay false.

note: you might consider using either xPts.length() or yPts.length() vs lineDiv. This would reduce the possibility of a array out of bounds exception assuming xPts and yPts have the same # of elements.